# Ajax search functionality that includes data from Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: ajax, wordpress, search, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to create a search function in Wordpress that uses AJAX to display both posts and a custom post type. So far I've managed to get almost everything working as I want it to, but searches for stuff that are being outputted with Advanced Custom Fields does not show up in the AJAX results.

**For example; I know that there's a mention of "Skittles" in one of my posts, but when I search for "Skittles" nothing is found in the AJAX results. The post containing the word "Skittles" is however found if I hit enter and end up at a separate search results page, but that is not the behavior I want.**

The code below makes custom fields searchable. Results show up on Wordpress' own search result page.

```
/**
* Finds custom fields meta data in search results
* http://adambalee.com
*/
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {    
        $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    }
    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );

function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );

function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( is_search() ) {
        return "DISTINCT";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

But I don't want people to end up at Wordpress' own search results page.

Here's the code I use for the AJAX search:

```
/**
* Adding ajax search functionality to the theme
* @return 
*/
function dhemy_ajax_search() { // creating a search query
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => array('case', 'post'),
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'order'          => 'DESC',
        'orderby'        => 'date',
        's'              => $_POST['term'],
        'posts_per_page' => 9999
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if($query->have_posts()) { // display results
        while ($query->have_posts()) { $query->the_post(); ?>

        <?php if(get_post_type() == 'case' ) { ?>
        <?php // code output for the cpt called 'case' ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <?php // code output for regular posts ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php }
    } else { ?>
        <?php // code output for when there are no hits ?>
    <?php } exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_dhemy_ajax_search', 'dhemy_ajax_search');
add_action('wp_ajax_dhemy_ajax_search', 'dhemy_ajax_search');
```

along with the javascript:

```
$('#bigsearch').keyup(function(event) {
    var searchTerm = $(this).val(); // get search term

    if(!searchTerm.trim()) {
        $('.search_overlay .flow .wrap .post_row').html('');
        return;
    }

    else if(searchTerm.length > 0) { // send request when the lenght is greater than 0 letters
        $.ajax({
            url: BASE+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: "post",
            data: {
                'action':'dhemy_ajax_search',
                'term':searchTerm
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $('.search_overlay .flow .wrap .post_row').fadeIn().html(result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Is it possible to include data from the custom fields in the `WP_query`'s `$args`? Or is it possible to combine the first functions with the actual search function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was in the code from [Adam Balée](https://adambalee.com/search-wordpress-by-custom-fields-without-a-plugin/). His code did the job, but but only if it was `is_search` and it wasn't in my case. What I did was to remove the `if ( is_search() ) {}` statement from the functions and it worked. So, the final code is:

```
/**
* Finds custom fields meta data in search results
* http://adambalee.com
*/
function cf_search_join( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;   
    $join .=' LEFT JOIN '.$wpdb->postmeta. ' ON '. $wpdb->posts . '.ID = ' . $wpdb->postmeta . '.post_id ';
    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join', 'cf_search_join' );

function cf_search_where( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where = preg_replace(
            "/\(\s*".$wpdb->posts.".post_title\s+LIKE\s*(\'[^\']+\')\s*\)/",
            "(".$wpdb->posts.".post_title LIKE $1) OR (".$wpdb->postmeta.".meta_value LIKE $1)", $where );
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'cf_search_where' );

function cf_search_distinct( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return "DISTINCT";
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'cf_search_distinct' );
```

A huge thanks to [Mattias Haal](https://github.com/kaloja) for helping me realize this.

Comment: thanks! I can get this to work but not really sure how you define what custom fields to include. Does this include all custom fields by default? thanks.

Comment: @v3nt yes, this includes all the custom fields by default. i guess that you can limit which custom fields are included in the query by tinkering around with the [`'meta_query'` parameter](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

Comment: @FilipR thanks. I've been looking at this but can't see how I would just search some custom fields. As it is now nearly all posts are being returned during search - including matches to sensitive backend only info (there is a lot of content & custom fields). I only want to include 3 custom fields for front end searches. We have ~130 custom fields.

Comment: @v3nt i'm sorry to hear that. i have to say that i don't know how make it work like you want it. have you tried to use `'relation'` in your meta_query? i don't know if that will do the trick but i would start there. See [this](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/exclude-posts-from-main-loop-based-on-acf-field-value/) link to better understand what i mean. hope it helps!